# Проблемы с отправкой сообщений через vk.net

Tags: c#, .net, vkontakte-api

При попытке отправки сообщения с помощью Vk.NET вылетает исключение `VkNet.Exception.AccessTokenInvalidException`

Авторизация и отправка сообщения выполняются с помощью разных кнопок:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                    
    string email = loginBox.Text;        
    string pass = textBox2.Text;               
    Settings scope = Settings.All;      

    var vk = new VkApi();
    VkApi vkapi = new VkApi();
    vk.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams
    {
        ApplicationId = appid,
        Login = email,
        Password = pass,
        Settings = scope
    });
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var vk = new VkApi();
    var send = vk.Messages.Send(new MessagesSendParams
    {
        UserId = userid,
        Message = "sample msg"
    });
}
```

В чем может заключаться проблема?

Answer (score 2):

Инстанс VkApi создается каждый раз новый. На одном мы авторизовались, а на втором нет. Нужно использовать один и тот же для совершения запросов, тогда авторизация не должна потеряться.

Comment: Как создать инстанс на всю программу без пересоздания в каждом классе?

Comment: @WaGe, ну так сходу в голову приходит либо синглтон, либо фасад статичный, ну или полем в классе с точкой входа.